# SVN Switch Relocate - is not the root of the repository

Tags: svn, relocation

I'm trying to move a working copy folder from it's old dedicated svn server, to a new svn server where it is contained within a sub-folder. Using the following relocate command:

```
svn switch --relocate https://oldserver/svn/repos https://newserver/some/directory
```

I get:

```
svn: 'https://newserver/some/directory ' is not the root of the repository
```

Which is correct ..... but, err, how do I move the location regardless?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can't use `svn switch` (with or without `--relocate`) to move to a new repository. Think about it this way: your new repository's HEAD revision is x, your old repository's revision is y, so what is SVN supposed to do with the working copy's base revision?

`svn help switch` says that `--relocate` is used to:

> Rewrite working copy URL metadata to reflect **a syntactic change only.** This is used when repository's root URL changes (such as a scheme or hostname change) but your working copy still reflects **the same directory within the same repository.**

Since this is not the case, I'm afraid you'll have to perform a fresh checkout.

Comment: however, i get the error, even though it really is the same dir within the same repo...

Comment: Well, I don't know if something has changed in the last 6 years, and I haven't researched the details thoroughly, but we just migrated our whole repository 'as-is' to a new server, and this command structure worked just fine to 'switch' existing checked-out work folders to work against the new repo: `svn switch --relocate svn://oldserver/ http://newserver/svn/goteam/`. i.e. - New protocol, new server, new folder spec. - Worked fine. Maybe SVN checks that the relevant repos are essentially the same and allows if so?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same operation, in this case I had a copy using svnsync in a file: url and moved it using mv /home/me/sync/therepo /home/me/sync/repos/therepo.

The reason: I have several help scripts in the sync catalog that mess up the view of the repos.

svn switch --relocate worked for the most part, except externals that keep complaining.

The solution was brutal: I deleted  (rm -rf) the directories with the offending files in them and ran svn update again to refetch the externals.

At least this way I did not have to do the large checkout again.

Also, now I can write instructions for my coworkers when we move the svn server to a new machine later on.

Answer (score 1):

What can happen too is that you are doing the relocate on a child of the root.

Try to do a relocate on the root folder. All the children folders will be automatically relocated too.

Answer (score 0):

Well im assuming youve already actually migrated the repository via `svnadmin dump`/`svnadmin load` so in that case you could try: `svn switch --relocate https://newserver/some/directory` If you get the same error you might actually have to just do a new `svn co`. I dont recall ever coming across that error but then all my repos use a nested structure like the one youre moving to so its possible ive never had to deal with it :-)

Comment: My repository was far too big for an easy svnadmin dump (it's used for binary files among others), so I svn co'd into a fresh directory and svn commited....

Comment: The repository is co'd to more than one location (live server, dev server, 2 devs machines etc). It's a big repository and I'd rather not have to download it all over again - reading into switch it seemed that switch could just change the url's that the repos used...