# SVN Error E195005: 'xyz' is not the root of the repository?

Tags: svn

I split one SVN repository into several repos as explained in http://www.mugo.ca/Blog/Splitting-a-Subversion-repository-into-multiple-repositories. However, I cannot execute the last step to relocate the existing working copies.

After running `svn relocate svn+ssh://user@server/newrepo` I get the following error:

```
svn: E195009: 'svn+ssh://user@server/newrepo' is not the root of the repository.
```

(However, for example I can checkout a new working copy from the new repository without any problems: `svn co svn+ssh://user@server/newrepo` gives me a fresh working copy of the newly created repo).

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVN Switch Relocate - is not the root of the repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155248/svn-switch-relocate-is-not-the-root-of-the-repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss one note from used HowTo

> **If you change the path**, step 6 regarding the "relocate" command **will
>   not work to re-point existing repository checkouts**. You would have to
>   do a **separate checkout** and then merge any differences.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when moving a project within the same repo to a different directory. For this you need "svn switch".  The rule is, from http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html:

- If the working copy needs to reflect a new directory within the repository, use svn switch.
- If the working copy still reflects the same repository directory, but
  the location of the repository itself has changed, use svn relocate.