# Intellij - SVN import with ignore

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

How do I set local svn repository in Intellij?

I have react-native project and I would like to use it with local svn , so I can sync between Windows and OSX where I build app for iOS.

The problem is that when I created project there was already some svn setup.

When I run commit I get this error:

```
E170013: Commit failed (details follow): svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/uds
```

But I do not want to use assembla and I do not even have account there. I would like to use local svn , I already have VisualSVN server running.

What I tried:
I tried to add Reposiotry in Intellij project and use import to import project folder there, but this does not follow ignore folder/files rules and node_modules are also imported there.

Then I tried VSC->Subversion->Replace and as new subversion I added my local address click ok and nothing happend, when I try to commit , Intellij is still trying to commit to assembla with same error.

Now when I click Relocate , I get this error:

```
"Error relocating working copy: svn: E1555019: Cannot relocate ... as it is not the root of working copy;"
```

But I am relocating root directory of project...

How do I set svn url to my local in Intellij project?????

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to get an SVN project in IntelliJ is just to check it out from the repository.

Relocate allows you to change the Repository URL, but the content of the new repository should be the same as the old one, see [SVN Switch Relocate - is not the root of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155248/svn-switch-relocate-is-not-the-root-of-the-repository)

With the current scenario, if you are not interested in the previous history, you could remove the existing `.svn` directory in the project and use **Subversion - Share directory...** from the context menu of the project root folder.

Comment: Hey , I followed your guide, deleted .svn directory , used Subversion -> Share directory and Intellij is stuck on  "Performing VCS commit..."

Comment: Are there any errors in the IDEA.log? 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085